# Python json difference between single quotes and double quotes

Tags: python, json, string, character-encoding

I have a flask app that I'm passing a request to. If I pass the request as

```
request= '{"vec": [436, 131, 51]}'
```

I get a successful response, but if I pass

```
request= "{'vec': [436, 131, 51]}"
```

it fails with "unable to evaluate payload provided" - so single vs double quotes seem to matter. The issue I'm having is that the output from another script is a stringified json object, but this seems to be stored with the key in single quotes. I'm trying to understand why they are handled differently, and if there's a way to force it to be in the correct.

Comment: This is a JSON problem, not a Python problem. The top one is valid JSON; the bottom one isn't. Whatever is generating your payload with single quotes isn't giving you valid JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[RFC7159](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7159) defining JSON stipulates

> A string begins and ends with quotation marks.

i.e. `"`, it does not allow `'` unlike `python`